# forwarding thingsboard Integrations incoming data to external incoming HTTP requests server

Tags: thingsboard

can someone please help me in this, i have created a HTTP Integrations in thingsboard and the data is being received as decoded json already for which i want to skip the step of adding the thingsboard javascript payload decoder function but that's a mandatory step i believe. how can i forward my incoming data which in is json to exteral http server as it is, please?

Here is my example integration that i have created and the payload that i receive
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXmcx.png)

now i want to forward the above message data to HTTP server using External - rest api call please see the example image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LMzE.png)

how can i achieve this please.

I tried everything mentioned above